# Change names of lists in list

Tags: r, list

I have list with elements "a" and "b" which are xts objects with length from 2010-01-01 to 2020-03-03

```
>List
 $a         col1 col2
 2020-01-01 7.50 50000     
 2020-01-02 7.55 40000 
 $b         col1 col2
 2020-01-01 4.50 50000     
 2020-01-02 4.70 35000
```

Then i use split() function to split them by week and the output is this:

```
>List
 $a[[1]]    col1  col2
 2020-01-01 7.50 50000
 $a[[2]]    col1  col2 
 2020-01-02 7.55 40000 
 $b[[1]]    col1  col2
 2020-01-01 4.50 50000
 $b[[2]]    col1  col2
 2020-01-02 4.70 35000
```

How can change lists names, because from this split function i get number to my elements name. 
I  am looking for this:

```
 >List
  $a          col1  col2
  2020-01-01  7.50 50000 
  $a          col1  col2 
  2020-01-02  7.55 40000
  $b          col1  col2
  2020-01-01  4.50 50000 
  $b          col1  col2
  2020-01-02  4.70 35000
```

Comment: Could you use `dput()` to show your data `List`?

Comment: dput is necessary here. hard to guess the structure from the print output . maybe unlist(List, recursive = FALSE)

Comment: My list was List with elements of $a and $b. I used split() and get this output - lists of lists. But i just want to keep names of my List without this IDs

Comment: If you run `dput(List)`, you will get some output in your console. Please copy that and paste to your post, then it would be easier for others to follow your question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
Listout<- setNames(unlist(lapply(List, function(x) split(x,seq(nrow(x)))),recursive = FALSE),
                   rep(names(List),sapply(List,nrow)))
```

such that

```
> Listout
$a
           col1  col2
2020-01-01  7.5 50000

$a
           col1  col2
2020-01-02 7.55 40000

$b
           col1  col2
2020-01-01  4.5 50000

$b
           col1  col2
2020-01-02  4.7 35000
```

**DATA**

```
List <- list(a = data.frame(col1=c(7.5,7.55),col2 = c(5e4,4e4),row.names = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02")),
             b = data.frame(col1=c(4.5,4.7),col2 = c(5e4,3.5e4),row.names = c("2020-01-01","2020-01-02")))
```